# tag abuse and tag editing

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, tag-abuse

I saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11189/what-to-do-about-tag-abuse) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70538/poisoning-of-api-related-tags-on-stack-overflow) and [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). To quote the *Death of Meta Tags* article:

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a
> meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as
> the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective],
> and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you
> nothing at all about the content of the question

I point to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11616468/revisions) where the original tags have [player](/questions/tagged/player) and [embedded-video](/questions/tagged/embedded-video) and even [flash-player](/questions/tagged/flash-player). At least [player](/questions/tagged/player) has no relevance to the question in my opinion. I would also think that [embedded-video](/questions/tagged/embedded-video) and even [flash-player](/questions/tagged/flash-player) also have no relevance to the question.

Question's tagged with [string](/questions/tagged/string) get abused as well.

Sometimes it seems that new users simply start typing and because their question has the word string in it (maybe in reference to an object type) that their question needs to be tagged that way.

So to my point. I don't want to edit out valid tags to a users question if it legitimately belongs there. Is it best to follow the quoted excerpt about a tag standing on its own?

Comment: [tag:Player] has over 500 questions, so unless you want to ask for a batch deletion, it's a lost cause.

Comment: [tag:embedded-video] doesn't seem particularly useful, but it doesn't seem particularly harmful either.

Comment: [tag:flash-player] -- meh.  At least it's specific.

Comment: [tag:string] is fine; everyone knows what that is.  Eh, I think you might be getting worked up for no discernible benefit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not suggesting necessarily to delete the tags all together, more about retagging question